# How to call a function when a div is dynamically generated using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The scenario I want to achieve is as follow:

```
$("#parentDiv").on("load",'#childDiv', function () {
        // do something...
});
```

I would like to call a function when a child div is dynamically generated and shown on the page, but there is no suitable event that can achieve this. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do it at the same place where the div is dynamically generated?

Comment: Or use the Observer pattern to notify other parts of the system that the component was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `load`, you can make use of a custom event which gets triggered with **[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("body").append("<div id='new'>Created</div>").trigger('custom-event');
  });
});

$(document).on("custom-event", function() {
  console.log('DIV created!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>Create element</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Love a good application of custom events!! Obsidian Age, you're my hero!